# Am I mutating the state when I use computed keys to modify state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to perform live form validation using React.

I have a radio button that asks the user if he already has an existing website. If his answer is yes, I need to validate the existing website text input. If the answer is no, I need not validate the existing website field and allow the user to submit.

**this.state.redesign** is controlled by the radio buttons yes and no.

In componentDidUpdate, I check if redesign has changed. If it has, I perform validation again by calling this.validate('existing_website').

The validate function checks if this.state.redesign is true and this.state.exsting_website == "". If yes, then it sets validation_error to true for that input field.

I am unable to achieve the desired result. When I click on the "Yes" radio button, the submit button still remains active.

In can see that when I click "Yes" componentDidUpdate is called and so is this.validate('existing_website').

The line

```
this.setState({[input_name]:input},()=>{  
        console.log(this.state[input_name]);
});
```

in the validate function also logs the updated state where I see this.state.existing_website.validation_error is set to true.

But the component does not rerender after this and the button remains active.

Any idea why this is happening? Please help me out guys! Thanks a lot in advance. Below is my full code.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    existing_website:{value:'',validate:true,validation_error:false,validation_message:"This field is necessary if you have selected yes above."},
    redesign:false
  }
  this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
}
getLabelAndInput(label,type,input_name){
     var field= <input type={type} name={input_name} value={this.state[input_name].value} onChange={(e)=>this.setInputValue(input_name,e.target.value)} onBlur={()=>this.inputBlur(input_name)} onFocus={()=>this.inputFocus(input_name)} className="width-100"/>
     return (
        <div className={"form-group"}>
          <label>{label}</label>
          {field}
          {this.state[input_name].validation_error?
            <p className="error">{this.state[input_name].validation_message}</p>
            :
            ''
          }
        </div>
      );
}
validate(input_name){
      var input = Object.assign({},this.state[input_name]);
      if(input.validate){
          if(input_name=="existing_website"){
          if(this.state.redesign && input.value==""){
            console.log('existing website validation error')
            input.validation_error = true;
          }
          else{
            console.log('existing website no validation error')
            input.validation_error = false;
          }
        }
      }
      this.setState({[input_name]:input},()=>{  
        console.log(this.state[input_name]);
      }); // Is this line mutating the state??
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
      if(prevState.redesign != this.state.redesign){
        console.log('redesign change')
        this.validate('existing_website');
      }
}
render(){
    console.log(this.state.existing_website.validation_error);
    let btnSubmit = <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</button>
    if(this.state.existing_website.validation_error){
        btnSubmit = <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" disabled>Submit</button>
    }
    return(
            <div className="form-group">

               <label className="highlight">Do you already have a website?</label>
               <span onClick={()=>this.setState({redesign:false},()=>{this.likedWebsitesRef.current.focus()})}><input type="radio" name="redesign" checked={!this.state.redesign}/> <span className="service_type_text">No</span></span>
               <span onClick={()=>this.setState({redesign:true})}><input type="radio" name="redesign" checked={this.state.redesign}/> <span className="service_type_text">Yes</span></span>

            </div>

           { this.state.redesign &&

              <div className="form-group">
                  {this.getLabelAndInput('Link to existing website','text','existing_website')}
              </div>

            }

            {btnSubmit}
    );
}
```

Edit:
**My console.log outputs:**

The boolean values below are from the console.log in the render function and indicate the value of this.state.existing_website.validation_error.

false // first rerender because of change in this.state.redesign

redesign change // console.log in componentDidUpdate due to above change

existing website validation error // validate function is called

false // render again.this was meant to happen after this.setState while console.logs below

{value: "", highlight: true, validate: true, validation_error: false, validation_message: "This field is necessary if you have selected yes above."}

//no rerender after this!

Comment: My best guess is that calling set state in componentDidUpdate is causing a re-render which causes componentDidUpdate to fire again potentially causing the validate fn to be called twice, once setting the state one way and again setting it back. I reccomend adding breakpoints to see what is happening.

Comment: I doubt because the set state is only called if "redesign" is different from prevState. In validate, I don't change redesign anywhere.